# Python 2.7: Simple 'for' loop implementation

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I am new to programming and I was having some difficulty understanding the logic behind a Python 'for' loop implementation example I came across:

```
s="abcdefg"
t=""
for a in s:
   t=a+t
```

I am confused as to why this piece of code returns "gfedcba." Why should it be any different from:

```
s="abcdefg"
t=""
for a in s:
   t=t+a
```

... which returns "abcdefg."

Comment: one puts the character at the end the other puts it at the front, if you print in the loop it should be pretty clear

Comment: Good  question, I didn't know that can reverse string like this :P. And by the way, this will also work on Python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the logic like this:

```
s="abcdefg"
t=""
```

These are the starting variables, now lets "unroll" the for loop. Keep in mind that "a" stands for each character of "s", from first to last:

```
t = a + t
```

so t = "a"

```
t = a + t
```

so t = "ba"

```
t = a + t
```

so t = "cba"

Concatenation is not like addition. Order matters!

Answer (score 5):

In effect, you are asking why `a + t` and `t + a` are not equivalent.

Here, `+` denotes [string concatenation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) rather than [addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition), and string concatenation is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property):

```
>>> "a" + "b"
'ab'
>>> "b" + "a"
'ba'
```

One way to think about your code is that

```
t = a + t
```

inserts `a` at the front of `t`, whereas

```
t = t + a
```

inserts it at the back.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loops in both snippets are identical. The difference lies with what you do with `t`. The first snippet **prepends** the character `a` in front of the string `t` in each iteration, effectively reversing the original string `s`. The second snippet **appends** the character `a` at the end of the string `t` in each iteration, effectively re-creating the original string `s`